# API call returns 408 (Your POST request is not being received quickly enough. Please retry) but works fine with Postman and ajax

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

Calling an external API from asp.net core 2.2 with framework 4.6.1 using `HttpClient` always returns `408` with an error message `Your POST request is not being received quickly enough. Please retry` but same code works fine with pure asp.net 2.2. The external API also works fine when I use Postman or ajax.

Here is the API call -

```
using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com/authenticate");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Empty, new JsonContent(data));
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, content);
}
```

Comment: Sounds similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628958/your-post-request-is-not-being-received-quickly-enough-please-retry

Comment: @phuzi remember it works fine with Postman and ajax call so it's not related to `Slow HTTP Post DDoS Attacks`